# Invalid JSON primitive: 103,104,105. - jqgrid - when passing an array to controller action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am using Multiselect feature to select multiple rows and pass to the controller. The javascript is below:

```
onClickButton: function (ids) {

var grid = $("#employee");
var rowid = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');

var count = rowid.length;
var rowData;
var colData = [];

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   rowData = $("#employee").getRowData(rowid[i]);
   colData[i] = rowData.ID;
                            }

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Home/Create/' + colData,
   //data: { id: colData },
    dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

My controller action is below:

```
public ActionResult Create(string id){
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var myList = ser.Deserialize<List<string>>(id);}
```

I am creating colData as an array and currently adding four IDs to it (“102,103,104,105”). When I debug and look at the colData, it contains “102,103,104,105”. Then, I pass it to the controller action as a string and then deserialize it. When I deserialize it, it complains as "Invalid JSON primitive: 103,104,105."

I have seen other posts but couldn't find anything related to my issue. When I pass colData using "data: { id: colData }", id is returned as null.

Please help me figure out this issue, it's been a while I am stuck with this one. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am passing colData to the controller and it contains the values as strings "102,103,104,105". Back in the controller action, the id is retrieved as the same. I have tried to retrieve as List<string> in the controller action but it then returned as null and hence retrieving as string and trying to deserialize the id, then it throws the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you are sending your data through ajax call you need to stringyfy your data like this

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("AddMe")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data:JSON.stringify({Id: colData}),
        dataType: "json",
success:function(){
       //do sth here
         }

         error: function () {
//do sth here
        }

        });
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution for the problem. Instead of sending the colData as an array, use Json.stringify to pass them as strings to the controller as below.

var data = Json.stringify(colData);

Then, pass "data" to the controller. The controller action should still retrieve it as string and deserializing the "id" would appropriately return list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a jsonstring with the following format.

```
var jsonstring = {idarray:[{"value":"102"},{"value":"103"}]}
```

Codebehind:

```
    public class Idarray
{
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Idarray> idarray { get; set; }
}
```